# How to prevent sympy from deleting the same values?

Tags: python, sympy

I have defined the following

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy import Max
x = sp.symbols('x', positive=True)
```

Now I calculate the maximum of several symbolic and non-symbolic values:

```py
s = Max(3, 5, 5, 4 * x, 2, 7 * x, 4 * x)
```

It is obvious, that since `x` is positive, that `s` is equal to 5 or 7*x; What I want as an answer is: Simplify such that values that cannot be the maximum are removed (i.e. 3 or 2 or 4*x) but leave the double values that could potentially be the maximum; So in this case I want as an answer:

```py
s = Max(5, 5, 7 * x)
```

Python correctly removes values that are not the maximum, but also kills double values that could potentially be the maximum, i.e. it returns

```py
s = Max(5, 7 * x)
```

How can I change that?

Comment: That looks correct to me: `Max(5, 5, 7*x)` is exactly the same as `Max(5, 7*x)`. If you want to know which values were duplicates look back to your original list.

Comment: Yes you are right but it is important for me to know the duplicates; Of course I do not have the original list but it is being calculated over many steps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to find out if there is more than one big value; if so, keep elements in `t` that have those values. And "those values" will be the args of the `Max` instance.

Something like this will work:

```
>>> t = (3,5,5,4*x,2,7*x,4*x)
>>> def allbig(t):
...   big = Max(*t)
...   if isinstance(big, Max): return tuple(i for i in t if i in big.args)
...   return (big,)
...
>>> allbig(t)
(5, 5, 7*x)
```